# Codeigniter Sparks with 3.0 Sparks_Path Error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am fairly new to Codeigniter (last 6 months) and just recently started learning about sparks and how to use them.  I followed Option 1 for installing Sparks [here from getsparks.org](http://getsparks.org/install) and I received the Spark Manager has been installed successfully message. I then went to install my first spark [found here](http://getsparks.org/packages/GoogleAPIClient/versions/HEAD/show) and received this message:  Spark installed to ./sparks/GoogleAPIClient/0.6.0 - You're on fire!

Upon trying to load my application I first had an error of EXT constant being undefined.  After reading some threads it was suggested I add `define('EXT', '.php');` to the application/config/constants.php file so I did.  Now when I try to access it I get an Error has occurred message with this:

```
Cannot find spark path at sparks/sparks/0.0.9/
```

I verified the setup was installed correctly for both the manager and my spark.  I read that adding `APPPATH . 'sparks/'` to the `SPARKPATH` constant would solve it (it didn't) and then trying `'../sparks/'` and that didn't.  What am I missing?

Using Codeigniter 3.0

Comment: simple - do not use sparks. that website was dead for a long time, and sparks is not supported in any way. just look at 'browse' - the last package is from a year and a half ago. basically sparks started in the time period before composer. composer is going to be the default package manager for a while and you can use it with codeigniter if you need to. otherwise the best place to find solutions, libraries, packages, helpers, etc for codeigniter is directly on github. you can also post to the codeigniter forum at http://forum.codeigniter.com

Answer (score 0):

Usually with codeigniter4, spark comes along with bundle however you can still try the following commands on terminal (codeigniter4 or older versions still works). I ran these commands on mac osx sierra 10.12 with php 8 and codeigniter3. Go to terminal and try command :

```
     $ php -r "$(curl -fsSL http://getsparks.org/go-sparks)"
```

it should give below output on terminal-

```
    "Pulling down spark manager from 
    http://getsparks.org/static/install/spark-manager-0.0.9.zip ...
    Pulling down Loader class core extension from 
    http://getsparks.org/static/install/MY_Loader.php.txt ...
    Extracting zip package ...
    Cleaning up ...
    Spark Manager has been installed successfully!"
```

you can then use below command to verify if everything works.

```
    php tools/spark help
```

it should return some text and description and some commands.